# Idk why adding javascript timers breaks my code. 44 failed github commits yesterday

Tags: javascript, html, github, timer

UPDATE: I want to thank everyone for trying to help. I never could get the code snippets integrated but thats my fault not yours :) I got some help with the javascript and we are not only up and running on bitvote.github com but we already had our first interview twitter com/EtherCasts/status/477566828513099777 , positive community response and 2 more interviews lined up for this week! ^_^ Thanks again stackexchange!

Original Problem:

I am trying to insert 4 javascript timers into my Proof-of-concept page at http://arkbg1.github.io/BitVote/

after a user clicks the "start here" button, one timer says "Current Time" in milliseconds then a data input table then a code log. I need it to have 4 timers instead of 1.

1. Registration Time: MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss   (static counter, capturing the time stamp of user click. similar to w3schools(.)com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_gettime except in MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss format.
2. Current Time: MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss   (counting live. similar to  w3schools(.)com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock
3. Spent Vote-Time: 00:00:00  (static counter. ignore this for now.)
4. Available Vote-Time: hh:mm:ss  (live counter, basic stop watch starting after click)

Every time I try to copy paste w3school code into my github code, the button/table script completely malfunctions or disappears. I tried 44 commits yesterday. nothings working and I dont know what im doing to break the current code or how to add these 4 basic timers without breaking the page.

here is the index.html and js.js - https://github.com/arkbg1/BitVote

Comment: Inconsistencies in your question make me wonder if you're using JavaScript or Java. Please fix.

Comment: What does "page breaks" mean? What is the exact error? Also don't use w3schools, it's terribly outdated, use MDN or another reference.

Comment: a js.js file is javascript, not java. and i mean when i try to copy paste the code in, not only does it not appear on the page correctly, but it often breaks the entire button/table script

Comment: MDN = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript ?

Comment: @arkbg1: That's right. MDN == Mozilla Developer Network

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to grab page elements with `document.getElementById` before the document is completely loaded. Try setting up a "main" function that runs `onload`. You can try something like this in you JS file. Then wherever you use those original variables get them from the `state` object.

```
var state;
window.onload = function() {
    state = {
        date: new Date(),
        spend_time: document.getElementById("spend_time"),
        button: document.getElementById("button"),
        spend_addr: document.getElementById("spend_addr"),
        power_time: document.getElementById("power_time"),
        progress: document.getElementById("progress"),
        passed: document.getElementById("passed"),
        to_fraction: document.getElementById("to_fraction"),
        amount_note: document.getElementById("amount_note"),
        spend_addr_note: document.getElementById("spend_addr_note"),
        old_spend_val: 0
    };
    voting(from_time() == 0);
    state.spend_time.value= state.old_spend_val;
    update_power_time();
    update_spend_addr();
};
```

**Timer Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer Test</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            setInterval(function () {
                var now = new Date(),
                    h = now.getHours(),
                    m = now.getMinutes(),
                    s = now.getSeconds();
                if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
                if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
                if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
                container.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            }, 500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, im a BRAND NEW coder, and this is my first time at stackoverflow (long time lurker and fan tho ^^) would i add that into the js.js or into the page.html? and where?

Comment: tyvm, tinkering with that now.

Comment: well, i added it in js.js lines 3-22 and it didnt break the button-table, but now how do i get the timers to display? can i copy paste basic HTML js timers from anywhere? here are a few ive been tinkering around with - http://pastebin.com/nhFNgkfr

Comment: @arkbg1 - You want something to repeat? If you use `setTimeout` it will only run once. Try using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: Oh I see you are calling the function itself which will in effect work like `setInterval`.

Comment: @arkbg1 - I put together a working example. You can probably use it to get things working.

Comment: UPDATE: I want to thank everyone for trying to help. I never could get the code snippets integrated but thats my fault not yours :) I got some help with the javascript and we are not only up and running on bitvote.github.com but we already had our first interview https://twitter.com/EtherCasts/status/477566828513099777 , positive community response and 2 more interviews lined up for this week! ^_^ Thanks again stackexchange!